# Laravel new project routing not working?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.6

Laravel new project routing not working? This is the routes.php file:

```
<?php

Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});

Route::get('ID/{id}',function($id){
    echo 'ID: '.$id;
});

Route::get('/user/{name?}',function($name = 'Virat Gandhi'){
    echo "Name: ".$name;
});
```

So what i have done is this. I started the local laravel development server with: php artisan serve. Just like the book told me that i am going through (Laravel 5). But now only the first routing works '/' which uses the welcome view blade template.

But all other routings don't work >.<

Can someone please help me? I'm stuck.

My app/public/htacess file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews -Indexes
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
    RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Is there an error? storage/logs/laravel.log?

Comment: Cool, i didn't know about that error log. Thanks. But no errors >.<

Comment: see answer @darthsoup return

Comment: Both echo and return are not making the routing work.

Comment: If you return return view('welcome'); into the other routes? Any errors in the Logs?

Comment: @Bas If i return the view template welcome into the other routes it gives me the same error: Sorry, the page you are looking for could not be found.

That's the error i get on the page. But in my laravel.log i get no errors displayed.

Comment: Post your htacces, app/public folder, that's i think the problem

Comment: cool, please post your answer and exept

Comment: I added the htacess file.

Answer (score 0):

I tried your all routes it's working fine.

Note:routes are case-sensitive make sure you are accessing the same route as you mentioned in the route.php

I tried below routes :

```
http://localhost:8000/user/1
return :Name: 1

http://localhost:8000/ID/1
return  :ID: 1
```

Comment: Yes i know that they are case-sensitive. It's not my first framework that i am learning. 

So i checked that. But it's still not working. 

I think it's maybe some settings in a htacess file or something like that. But i have no experience with such files yet

Comment: As your title is regarding route not working i make sure your routes are working properly

Comment: Can you please share which route you are trying to access and exactly what error you are facing in that route?

Comment: Yeah but i don't know what the problem is. So that's why i am asking for help on StackOverflow.

Comment: Route::get('ID/{id}',function($id){
    echo 'ID: '.$id;
});

It said: Sorry, the page you are looking for could not be found.

Comment: in the browser which exactly route you type can you please share ?

Comment: use lowercase in the url and in your routes

Comment: just serve your project and save all files go to browser and type this http://localhost:8000/ID/1    (note your locolhost port may be different for me its 8000 using xamp)

Comment: @PrashantPrajapati it's not working for me. I already tried that a lot of times in a row.

Comment: just let me know the route you type in url

Comment: @PrashantPrajapati do i need to start an Apache server? Doesn't Laravel have their own Apache server?!

Comment: @PrashantPrajapati localhost:8000/ID/1

Comment: Just open your xamp and run both the services apache and mysql laravel dosnt have their own

Comment: @PrashantPrajapati Oh.. i was thinking Laravel used their own Apache server when i hit php artisan serve..

So that's the problem...

where can i see the apache settings in my Laravel project files to check the ports?

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `return` not `echo`

Like this:

```
Route::get('ID/{id}', function($id) {
    return 'ID: ' . $id;
});
```

Comment: @darthsoup both echo and return work's here. i tried from my end can you just try echo he is having some other issue then the route i think soo.

Answer (score 0):

I tried your all routes it's working fine.

Note:routes are case-sensitive make sure you are accessing the same route as you mentioned in the route.php

I tried below routes :

```
http://localhost:8000/user/1
return :Name: 1

http://localhost:8000/ID/1
return  :ID: 1
```

**Note : make sure you run apache & mysql services from xamp before you serve you project.**

Comment: Where can i edit my portnumber in my Laravel project? My lampp Apache port is 80. But i don't know where i should change that. Which settings file of Laravel do i need to change?

Comment: what do you use xamp,wamp anyother mention please?

Comment: Lampp, Apache2, port 80

Comment: php artisan serve --port 80

Comment: I first started my lampp apache and after that i started the php artisan serve --port 80 command. But it said this:

[Mon Mar 19 11:02:02 2018] Failed to listen on 127.0.0.1:80 (reason: Address already in use)

Comment: That port address is already in use try using  php artisan serve --port 8080

Comment: Do i not need to use the same artisan port as my lampp apache port number? Why is it different then 80? Can u explain that? I am going to test it now.

Comment: And it doesn't work. Same error pages as before with the message: Sorry, the page you are looking for could not be found.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry i'm not able to tell this in the comments above as i don't have enough rep.

I think the problem is your mixing the servers you are using. First try launching your LAMP server and start apache and mysql. Since you've said that the apache launched by LAMP is pointed at port 80, you can try and access it directly on the browser (e.g. http://localhost/yourproject/public/user/1).

I'm guessing since you're using LAMP, your project is under the www root. That's why i've entered the full path for accessing the user route.